# How do I get Failed results when using GORM batch creation?

Tags: go, orm, go-gorm

I am trying to create records using the Gorm CreateInBatches method. I do not want to fail the complete batch operation if there is any conflict so I am using the gorm clause to ignore conflicts, but I am unable to get failed records with this approach. Is there a way to get the failed records when using batching with ignore clause in Gorm?

code:

```
gormDbClient.Clauses(clause.OnConflict{DoNothing: true}).CreateInBatches(users, 500)
```

Comment: There is no way to get failed rows rather you can do an `IN` query by your unique columns and get the conflicts before creating.